# Scala Cats Effect Wrapping an Implementation from the Effect Type of the Enclosing Class

Tags: scala, generics, scala-cats, doobie

I have an implementation that looks like this:

```
final class MyServiceImpl[M[_]: Async](dbCfg: DBConfig)(implicit ec: Scheduler) extends MyService[M] {
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ......
}
```

Inside this class I have some methods that uses doobie to run sql queries against the database. As I was testing them, I felt the need to log these queries and doobie has a nice way to get this done which is to implement the trait `LogHandler[M[_]]`

I can then have this inside MyServiceImpl like this as stated from doobie's documentation:

```
val printSqlLogHandler: LogHandler[IO] = new LogHandler[IO] {
  def run(logEvent: LogEvent): IO[Unit] = 
    IO { 
      println(logEvent.sql)
    }
}
```

That example uses IO, but I would prefer to use the effect type that MyServiceImpl gets instantiated with. How can I do this?

Comment: Just use `F` instead of `IO` and maybe ask for a `Console[F]` so you can use a proper `println`

Comment: It complains here: val logHandler: LogHandler[M] = new LogHandler[M]  as wrong number of type parameters. Expected 0 actual 1

Comment: I guess I'm not importing the LogHandler trait from doobie.

Answer (score 0):

At first create class like follow:

```
trait MyLogHandler[M[_]] {
  def log(logEvent: LogEvent): M[Unit]
}
```

Secondly impeliment to your class:

```
class MyCustomLogHandler[M[_]: Async] extends LogHandler[M] with MyLogHandler[M] {
  def log(logEvent: LogEvent): M[Unit] =
    Async[M].delay {
      println(logEvent.sql)
    }
}
```

at the end you can use it like follow:

```
final class MyServiceImpl[M[_]: Async](dbCfg: DBConfig)(implicit ec: Scheduler) extends MyService[M] {

  val logHandler: LogHandler[M] = new MyCustomLogHandler[M]

  // ...
}
```

Comment: It would be better to ask for `: Console` in addition to `: Async` and then do `Console[M].println` instead of using `delay`

Comment: First of all, make sure you have access to a Console type class that can handle logging in your effect type M. You can add it as an implicit parameter in your MyServiceImpl:
`final class MyServiceImpl[M[_]: Async: Console](dbCfg: DBConfig)(implicit ec: Scheduler) extends MyService[M] {
  ...
  ...
  ...
}`

Comment: then, you can define a custom LogHandler that uses Console[M].println:
`val customLogHandler: LogHandler[M] = new LogHandler[M] {
  def run(logEvent: LogEvent): M[Unit] = 
    Console[M].println(logEvent.sql)
}`
by adding Console[M]: Console as an implicit parameter, you ensure that the Console type class is available for logging in your effect type M. This way, you can use Console[M].println to log SQL queries with the effect type that your MyServiceImpl is using.